# $window.height is not a function Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using infinite scroll directive and this is the code:

```
 angApp.directive('infiniteScroll', [
            '$rootScope', '$window', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, $window, $timeout) {
                return {
                    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                        var checkWhenEnabled, handler, scrollDistance, scrollEnabled;
                        $window = angular.element($window);
                        scrollDistance = 0;
                        if (attrs.infiniteScrollDistance != null) {
                            scope.$watch(attrs.infiniteScrollDistance, function (value) {
                                return scrollDistance = parseInt(value, 10);
                            });
                        }
                        scrollEnabled = true;
                        checkWhenEnabled = false;
                        if (attrs.infiniteScrollDisabled != null) {
                            scope.$watch(attrs.infiniteScrollDisabled, function (value) {
                                scrollEnabled = !value;
                                if (scrollEnabled && checkWhenEnabled) {
                                    checkWhenEnabled = false;
                                    return handler();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        handler = function () {
                            var elementBottom, remaining, shouldScroll, windowBottom;
                            console.log($window);
                            windowBottom = $window.height() + $window.scrollTop();
                            elementBottom = elem.offset().top + elem.height();
                            remaining = elementBottom - windowBottom;
                            shouldScroll = remaining <= $window.height() * scrollDistance;
                            if (shouldScroll && scrollEnabled) {
                                if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
                                    return scope.$eval(attrs.infiniteScroll);
                                } else {
                                    return scope.$apply(attrs.infiniteScroll);
                                }
                            } else if (shouldScroll) {
                                return checkWhenEnabled = true;
                            }
                        };
                        $window.on('scroll', handler);
                        scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                            return $window.off('scroll', handler);
                        });
                        return $timeout((function () {
                            if (attrs.infiniteScrollImmediateCheck) {
                                if (scope.$eval(attrs.infiniteScrollImmediateCheck)) {
                                    return handler();
                                }
                            } else {
                                return handler();
                            }
                        }), 0);
                    }
                };
            }
    ]);
```

The problem with this code is sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. If I do a hard refresh by pressing Ctrl + F5 it most certainly throws the below error.

This is the error:

[image]

I am using Firefox 29.0.1. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have jquery included before angular?

Comment: Yes, I am using requireJS and it's loaded before infinite scroll. Screenshot here: http://gyazo.com/4bb9b7fedcc5d624b89b9c873c96eb72

Comment: Try using $() instead to make sure you are using jquery

Comment: awesome. That is working even in hard refresh. Question is how? And this code was not written by me. It's from infinite scroll directive of angularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this should work, but there might be some problem with requireJS. Using `$()` instead should ensure you are using Jquery. You might need the [order](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#order) plug-in for requireJS since `normally RequireJS loads and evaluates scripts in an undetermined order.`